# Rockwood NY6510 cabinet design and online calculator

Tags: speakers, sub-bass

I want to build a cabinet form a Rockwood NY6510 subwoofer. 
In order to get an idea of the cabinet design  I use two online software:

The one from [ajdesing](http://www.ajdesigner.com/fl_subwoofer/subwoofer.php) and the one from [diyaudioandvideo](http://www.diyaudioandvideo.com/Calculator/Box) .
with the same input parameters, I get from the speaker [datasheet](http://boxenbastler.de/Rockwoodny6510)

```
Fs = 55.7 Hz
Qms = 3.5
Qes = 1.2
Vas = 17.0 lt
Qts = 0.9
```

I choose

Qtc = 1.0
Port diameter = 10cm
Ported Box desing

I'm confused since I get two completly different results using the same input parameters .

From  [diyaudioandvideo](http://www.diyaudioandvideo.com/Calculator/Box) I get

```
Vb = 8.48 ft3  =  240.15 lts
= L x W x H
f3 = 17.37 Hz
fb = 24.51 Hz
Dv = 1 in  =  2.5 cm
Lv = -0.39 in  =  -0.98 cm
```

But from [ajdesing](http://www.ajdesigner.com/fl_subwoofer/subwoofer.php) 
I get a negative f3 = -29 and the fb = Fs = 55.7.

Did I made some mistake? Which online sfw should I trust?

The results for the closed box design are the same for both the appliations:

```
Vb = 2.56 ft3  =  72.47 lts
= L x W x H
f3 = 48.65 Hz
fb = 61.89 Hz
```

Thanks

Comment: This is off topic here - your best bet is to either find another site to compare (see if it agrees with one of these two) or contact support on one of them. It sounds like perhaps they interpret one of the parameters differently, perhaps a decimal point, but you'd need to ask them.